# how to add menu item to own module - OpenERP 7

Tags: python, odoo

when i need to add 'supplier menu item' to my own module, i need to copy and paste below tag & add hr & base models in depends section of **openerp**.py file .? is it enough.? any other modification need to do.?

```
<menuitem id="base.menu_procurement_management_supplier_name" name="Suppliers"
    parent="menu_procurement_management"
    action="base.action_partner_supplier_form" sequence="15"/>
```

i try this method to payroll menu item also.then its moved from that module to my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace parent menu with your own module menu id where you want to display.

Like your menuitem example:

```
parent="menu_procurement_management"
```

is purchase module menuitem id, so it displays menu under the purchase order menu. When you replace it with your menu item id it will display it under your menu item.

You can change the sequence as per you module requirement.

Hope this is helpful to you

Comment: thanks friend.,seems my earlier issue with sequence number  :-)